# Having problems creating a scrollable boxlayout but im having problems

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a scrollable horizontal box layout where a picture would be in front and if you scroll to the left the next picture would show and it continues like that but im having issues all the pictures are just in the front screen and there is no scrollable effects im tried different methods but to know avail. if someone could solve this for me i would appreciate it below is a sample of my code

Here is the BoxLayout

```
class PictureLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PictureLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        self.height = self.minimum_height
        self.spacing = 20
        self.padding = [10, 10]
        self.size_hint_y = 1
```

Here are the images

```
class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.scrollview = ScrollView(pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}, size_hint = (1, 0.8))
        self.add_widget(self.scrollview)

        self.stack = PictureLayout()
        self.scrollview.add_widget(self.stack)




        self.sampleimage = ImageButton(source="icons/addimage.png",
                                           size_hint=(0.9, None))
        self.sampleimage.bind(on_release=self.sampleimagechange)
        self.stack.add_widget(self.sampleimage)

        self.sampleimage2 = ImageButton(source="icons/addimage.png",
                                            size_hint=(0.9, None))
        self.sampleimage2.bind(on_release=self.sampleimagechange2)
        self.stack.add_widget(self.sampleimage2)

        self.sampleimage3 = ImageButton(source="icons/addimage.png",
                                            size_hint=(0.9, None))
        self.sampleimage3.bind(on_release=self.sampleimagechange3)
        self.stack.add_widget(self.sampleimage3)

        self.sampleimage4 = ImageButton(source="icons/addimage.png",
                                            size_hint=(0.9, None))
        self.sampleimage4.bind(on_release=self.sampleimagechange4)
        self.stack.add_widget(self.sampleimage4)

        self.sampleimage6 = ImageButton(source="icons/addimage.png",
                                            size_hint=(0.9, None))
        self.sampleimage6.bind(on_release=self.sampleimagechange6)
        self.stack.add_widget(self.sampleimage6)
```

Comment: What happens if you set `size_hint_x = None` in your `PictureLayout`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson the Boxlayout disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `width` of the `PictureLayout` to something larger than the `width` of the `ScrollView`. For example, the following will work:

```
class PictureLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PictureLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        self.spacing = 20
        self.padding = [10, 10]
        self.size_hint_y = 1
        self.size_hint_x = None
        self.width = 3000
```

A better approach would be to use the `kv` language:

```
class PictureLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

kv = '''
ProfileWindow:
    name: 'profile'
<PictureLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 20
    padding: [10, 10]
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.minimum_width
'''

class HSApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
```

This uses the `minimum_width` property of a `BoxLayout`, but for this to work, you must set the size of each `ImageButton` (setting `size_hint` will not work). Note that using `self.minimum_height` or `self.minimum_width` in python code uses the value of that property at the time that the python code is executed. Using that same property in `kv` (as `width: self.minimum_width`) also sets up a binding, so that when `minimum_width` of the `PictureLayout` changes, its `width` will also change

Comment: Thank you very much bro, but its not scrolling now

Comment: Working now bro ! appreciate all your help